# Scope of work contents in freelance development

Tags: freelancing, scope

One of my clients demanded to append screen shots of UI in the SOW. Also, I was asked to give a workflow diagram for the same. The project I am about to take is relatively small and my question is,

- Should we always provide UI snap shots before project begins? (at least basic). Personally I feel this is not possible as UI keeps changing until agreed upon by client, which is waste of time before development.
- Is it necessary to provide both Data Flow Diagram (DFD) and UI screen shot before development begins?

Comment: What's a DFD?  A Data Flow Diagram?  The UI is a different thing.

Comment: Yes Data flow Diagram , UI is a different thing am asking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provide what the client wants.  If you want them as a client that is.

Having some mock ups for the UI is probably a good idea.  Covers your ass too.  You want there to be some decent detail in what the program is meant to do so the client doesn't keep coming up with new and wonderful things to add without paying.

It's true that there will be some evolution, but as stuff like that comes up you can amend the scope to reflect new agreements.  The cool thing there is that it requires your agreement.

So while I've not done much freelancing myself, it seems to me like a good idea to have a nice, detailed scope explaining what the program will do and more or less what it will look like.  I'd use some RAD tool for prototyping the UI...Qt designer or something.  If you can do it in the system you'll build the product in, all the better.

Where I currently work we actually have to do this kind of crap even for internal projects.  We treat the mucky-mucks like clients because they demand it.  Not allowed to do much of anything without 50 miles of paper and a month in committee.

Comment: tnx for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

> Should we always provide UI snap shots before project begins?

If that's what the client asks for, yes.

> UI keeps changing until agreed upon by client

Then get the client to agree on the UI design.

> Is it necessary to provide both DFD and UI screen shot before development begins?

If the client asks for it, yes.  You can always state your case, and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "always" answer - you do what is necessary to fulfill the terms of the contract, deliver a working solution, make a happy customer and get paid! (Or you decide that the job isn't for you and decline the work, although I wouldn't let that become a habit...)

Workflow and UI can both evolve during the life of a project which may make any detailed documentation you do now redundant but there's nothing wrong with providing some prototype / mockup screens as long as you make them clear that's all they are.

The client may also want the documentation as a form of reassurance that you understand their problem and aren't going to go shooting off on a wild (and expensive) tangent. So do it, if it makes them happy.